# Why using unix-compress and go compress/lzw produce different files, not readable by the other decoder?

Tags: go, compression, file-format, lzw

I compressed a file in a terminal with `compress file.txt` and got (as expected) `file.txt.Z`

When I pass that file to `ioutil.ReadFile` in Go,

```
buf0, err := ioutil.ReadFile("file.txt.Z")
```

I get the error (the line above is 116):

```
finder_test.go:116: lzw: invalid code
```

I found that Go would accept the file if I compress it using the `compress/lzw` package, I just used code from [a website](https://www.socketloop.com/references/golang-compress-lzw-newwriter-function-example) that does that. I only modified the line

```
outputFile, err := os.Create("file.txt.lzw")
```

I changed the `.lzw` to `.Z`. then used the resulting `file.txt.Z` in the Go code at the top, and it worked fine, no error.

Note: `file.txt` is 16.0 kB, unix-compressed `file.txt.Z` is 7.8 kB, and go-compressed `file.txt.Z` is 8.2 kB

Now, I was trying to understand why this happened. So, I tried to run

```
uncompress.real file.txt.Z
```

and it did not work. I got

```
file.txt.Z: not in compressed format
```

I need to use a compressor (preferably `unix-compress`) to compress files using `lzw-compression` then use the same compressed files on two different algorithms, one written in C and the other in Go, because I intend to compare the performance of the two algorithms. The `C` program will only accept the files compressed with `unix-compress` and the Go program will only accept the files compressed with Go's `compress/lzw`.

Can someone explain why that happened? Why are the two .Z files not equivalent? How can I overcome this?

Note: I am working on Ubuntu installed in VirtualBox on a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .Z file does not only contain LZW compressed data, there is also [a 3-bytes header](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Development:_Z_File_Format) that the Go LZW code does not generate because it is meant to compress data, not generate a Z file.

Comment: Or maybe the smarter thing to do would be to just read a unix-compressed .Z file in Go, and just omit the first 3 bytes. Am I right?

Comment: One of those, yes. Then, that same page also suggests that compress uses a custom version of LZW, so it may still not be enough. In that case, you could experiment with GIF files instead.

Comment: In the [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/200b/2261e11ddeb25298d6367db553a184af73fc.pdf) of one of the algorithms I'm using, they use unix-compress, so, I will use it. Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: after this line `buf0, err := ioutil.ReadFile("file.txt.Z")` i took a slice from I did `buf3 := buf0[3:]` and then used the slice `buf3` instead. It still gives me the same error

Comment: As I wrote above, the page I linked to suggests that compress uses a custom version of LZW, which may not be compatible with Go’s implementation.

Comment: Oh yes, it makes sense now. I'm trying to figure out a way to modify the Go code to read the LZC variant of LZW.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you only want to test the performance of two of your/some third party algorithms (& not the compression algorithms themselves), you may want to write a shell script which calls the compress command passing the files/dir's required and then call this script from your C / GO program. This is one way you can overcome this, but leaves open other parts of your queries on the correct way to use the compression libraries.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ancient bug named ["alignment bit groups"](https://github.com/vapier/ncompress/issues/5) behind this question. I've described it in wikipedia ["Special output format"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compress). Please read.

I've implemented a new library [lzws](https://github.com/andrew-aladev/lzws). It has all possible options:

1. `--without-magic-header` (`-w`) - disable magic header
2. `--max-code-bit-length` (`-b`) - set max code bit length (9-16)
3. `--raw` (`-r`) - disable block mode
4. `--msb` (`-m`) - enable most significant bit
5. `--unaligned-bit-groups` (`-u`) - enable unaligned bit groups

You can use any options in all possible combinations. All combinations has been tested. I am sure that you can find combinations suitable for go lzw implementation.

You can use [ruby-lzws](https://github.com/andrew-aladev/ruby-lzws) binding if you like to use ruby.