# What are the modifications needed to make this Go program read LZC instead of LZW?

Tags: unix, go, compression, pattern-matching, file-format

I am using an open source, third-party Go package: [comprfind](https://bitbucket.org/jasiekmarc/comprfind/src). The package implements a famous compressed pattern matching algorithm from the paper "Let sleeping files lie: Pattern matching in Z-compressed files." by Amir, Benson, and Farach. And it is supposed to take an LZW compressed text file `file.Z` (I need it to be compressed with `unix-compress`) and a pattern (`string`) and find the locations where the pattern occurs in the text of `file.Z`.

I am just using the testing tool, without a `main func`. At the moment, for simplicity, I am only focusing on `func TestBigData` for debugging and initial testing.

Wen I tried to give it a unix-compressed `file.txt.Z`, it gave me the error

```
finder_test.go:113: lzw: invalid code
```

Apparently, the way the package is implemented, it is only accepting LZW compressed data from a `[]byte` as seen in `finder_test.go`. The only way I could make it work is to compress a file with Go'z `compress/lzw` .I used (the code in the first link in comment bellow), but istead of `.lzw` I put `.Z` and use the output as input to `comprfinder`.

I need the `comprfind` code to accept unix-compressed `.Z` files. So I tried to ignore the header bytes by doing the following:

after `buf0, err := ioutil.ReadFile("file.txt.Z")` (in `func TestBigData` in `finder_test.go`) I took a slice by doing `buf3 := buf0[3:]` and then used `buf3` instead of `buf0` in subsequent lines.

And I still got the same error.

From .Z file extension documentation (second link in comment) I found that `.Z` files generated by `unix-compress` actually use LZC algorithm (a very close variant of LZW). This seems to be the reason why `comprfind` is not able to read the `.Z` file.

How can I modify `comprfind` source code to read the LZC version instead of LZW? Any tip or suggestion will be of great help.

Note: I am working on Ubuntu installed in VirtualBox on a Mac.

P.S.: Some information provided above, I learnt from [Zoyd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42889912/4725811) to a related question that I posted before.

Comment: [compress/lzw example](https://www.socketloop.com/references/golang-compress-lzw-newwriter-function-example)

Comment: [Z File Format](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Development:_Z_File_Format)